# Is this method that returns a DataTable safe from SQL injection?

Tags: c#-4.0

I have the following function:

```
public DataTable GetRecordSet(String query, string[] parameters)
```

It is typically used as follows:

```
DataTable dt = GetRecordSet( "select * from objects where ob_id = @obid and ac_id = @acid", new[] { objectId, accountId });
```

The GetRecordSet method parses the query parameter looking for words preceded by @ and create appropriate SqlParameter objects that's passed into a SqlCommand object. In this case, two parameters would be created.

The query parameter will be always be supplied by me, the parameters array may have data from the user.

I am concerned that because I'm generating the parameter names from a string, that I may somehow be inadvertently circumventing anti-SQL injection countermeasures. Is this method safe?

Update:
GetRecordSet gets a select command as follows:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand = GetSqlCommand(query, parameters);
```

The GetSqlCommand method:

```
private SqlCommand GetSqlCommand(string query, string[] parameters)
{
    SqlCommand sq = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);

    // enum parameters
    // get name of parameter from the query string and add it to the SqlCommand
    SqlParameter p;
    string[] paramNames = query.Split('@');
    string name;

    int paramCounter = 0;
    if (parameters != null)
    {
        foreach (string param in parameters)
        {
            paramCounter += 1;
            if (param != "")
            {
                try
                {
                    if (paramNames.Length > paramCounter)
                    {
                        name = paramNames[paramCounter].Split(' ')[0];

                        p = new SqlParameter(name, param);
                        sq.Parameters.Add(p);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return sq;
}
```

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing `GetRecordSet`. Though since it uses parameters, it should be safe.

Comment: Updated question with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code above is safe from SQL Injection - there is a way to exploit [parameter names](http://blog.portswigger.net/2008/08/attacking-parameter-names.html), but this code is safe from that particular issue.

Of course there is no way to be 100% certain, but this is as good as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

No.  The only way to pass parameters from the outside world is if have been explicitly
identified or properly quoted.   It is never safe to just insert ANY block of text into
a query.